# Will MessageSource in Spring Boot allow using multiple properties files for the same language?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, internationalization

I want to have a dependency jar which holds the base properties files for the main languages we support. So inside the jar will be:

```
i18n/messages_en_US.properties
i18n/messages_fr.properties
```

This jar is pulled in via a gradle compile dependency:

```
compile(group: "com.mycompany", name: "localization", classifier: "lite", version: "1.0.0")
```

I want the developers to be able to also add any custom messages they might need in their project too. So they might have:

```
resources/i18n/messages_en_US.properties
resources/i18n/messages_fr.properties
```

And I want the `MessageSource` bean to use the combination of the ones that are in the jar *and* in the dev's project. Is this possible?

Would I need to implement a bean to make it happen?

Comment: You can add multiple bundles that have distinct names.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can configure more than one baseName, there is a method setBasenames(String... basenames) in AbstractResourceBasedMessageSource class, so when you are setting baseNames for the MessageSource bean then you need to add all the paths which have properties files.

Comment: But will it allow combining multiple ones for the same language? Does it actually do this?

Comment: Can you try to run this for confirmation?

Comment: @DonRhummy Yes, it works. I've done this for Web internationalization with Spring.